# How to export file from your app to others mobile app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, gamekit

I want to put sharing feature in my application so that i can share file created in my app to app on others mobile. Please if anybody has any idea or code let me know....:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the ways I can think of -

1. Send your file as mail attachement as @Akshay points out.
2. Use [**Gamekit framework**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) in iOS to transfer data between iOS devices without internet.
3. You could use Bluetooth, but essentially I think GameKit uses that. so you might as well go with gamekit instead of (re)defining your own protocol...

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

You can compose a new email using `MFMailComposeViewController` and attach the file.

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [controller addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path] mimeType:mimeType fileName:[path lastPathComponent]]; //path is the path to your file

    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
```

For iOS 5.0 or later, you could use iCloud.

HTH,

Akshay